# TexMaker displays only squares in open/save windows

Tags: texmaker

I installed TexMaker in Archlinux. I followed the tutorial on TexMaker website, and still have this problem:
[The open/save windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0SUz.png)
[The TexMaker configuration windown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfiiU.png)

When I open or save a file, the window displays only squares. I don't have this problem anywhere else. I tried to google, but couldn't find the similar problem. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like TexMaker tries to use some fonts you haven't installed or they are broken somehow. Afaik it uses courier new.

Comment: Installing the courier font fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice, usually that doesn't go so quickly. I reposted my comment as an answer, please accept it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like TexMaker tries to use some fonts you haven't installed or they are broken somehow. Afaik it uses Courier New.